# Running A Rom with the Emulator Specified in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am writing an rom launcher for emulators in VB.NET. Currently I can make it launch the emulator but the selected ROM doesn't load with it. My code is as follows...

```
Process.Start("C:\Users\SighFye\Documents\zsnesw151\zsnesw.exe", "shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL " & "C:\RetroGames\nintendo\Super Nintendo\AlienvsPredator\AlienvsPredator.smc")
```

How do I get it to run the ROM when it launches the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The path to the rom has spaces in it so I needed to put quotes in the string

```
Process.Start("C:\Users\SighFye\Documents\zsnesw151\zsnesw.exe", "shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL " & """C:\RetroGames\nintendo\Super Nintendo\AlienvsPredator\AlienvsPredator.smc""")
```